# Комбинация клавиш для установления заголовка в терминале?

Tags: linux, терминал

Какая комбинация клавиш позволяет установить заголовок в терминале ?

Какой терминал:

Командой `echo $TERM` получаю **xterm**
Через *Справка -> О программе* получаю **Терминал среды MATE** версии 1.18.1

Comment: В какой ос?????

Comment: У меня по умолчанию вообще нет комбинации.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под заголовком ?
Эмулятор терминала ? Например: `Konsole`, `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @stackflow а вот у меня такого нет. Так какой вы используете эмулятор терминала ?

Comment: вероятно, в подавляющем числе эмуляторов терминала — никакая. (по крайней мере мне ни одного такого эмулятора не известно). если эмулятор поддерживает такие же escape-последовательности, как и *xterm*, то см.: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько способов изменить заголовок окна, взависимости от используемого *эмулятора терминала* или текущей оболочки, например: `bash`.

> Первый пример. Для *открытия* эмулятора терминала. 
>   Далее эмулятор терминала - **ЭТ**.

1. ЭТ среды **Mate** (mate-terminal).

   - Для открытия новой сессии, напечатайте:`mate-terminal --title=Кодинг`
2. ЭМ среды **GNOME** (gnome-terminal).

   - Для открытия новой сессии, напечатайте: `gnome-terminal --title="Музыка"`
3. ЭМ среды **KDE** (konsole).

   - Для открытия новой сессии, напечатайте: `konsole -p tabtitle='Гитхаб'`
4. ЭМ среды **X** (xterm). Для открытия новой сессии, напечатайте:

   - `xterm -xrm 'XTerm.vt100.allowTitleOps: false' -T Книги`

> Второй пример. Взависимости от используемой оболочки, на примере: `bash`.

1. `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Красивый заголовок\007"'`
2. `echo -ne "\033]0;Заголовок красивый\007"`